# How to exclude spring configuration files with @Configuration for dependency on other project

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, maven-3

I have a project say A[In Maven] which has dependency on project B[In Maven]. Now project B got some spring @Configuration[db configuration ] files which gets up when i build and deploy my project A but due to some config properties which I don't have in my project A it shows some error. So how can I exclude that configuration files in project A while using other dependency in project B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add excludeFilters in your component scan to skip the class

```
@ComponentScan(value = {'your.package.here'}, excludeFilters = @Filter(ConfigurationToIgnore.class))
```

Comment: can i have equivalent of that for .xml configuration

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here" />`

Comment: Ok found one   <context:exclude-filter>