# Spring Boot app "bean name for bean class conflicts with existing" - how to exclude package/Class from 3rd party library/dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I have a Spring Boot application that I recently migrated from 1.x.x to 2.x.x. I am using a few 3rd party libraries/JARs to do some logging of metrics using Prometheus.

The problem is I have (2) Java Classes named `PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration` that are both annotated with `@Configuration` and I'm getting the infamous Spring exception:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'prometheusServletAutoConfiguration' for bean class [com.my.package.path1.PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.my.package.path2.PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration]
```

So as you see, they do have slightly different FQDN (full qualified domain names, or package paths AND I simplified it for this example as you can see) but the main class is the same name so I think Spring is trying to figure out which Bean to create and failing. This utterly perplexes me, and I looked at the code/libraries in IntelliJ with Spring 1.x.x off the old branch code, and **this exception was never thrown** (was it ignored in Spring 1.x.x or something?). I also will note the code compiles fine, but fails at Runtime (makes sense)

Was is the best resolution here? Should I just tell Spring to NOT scan one of these classes FQDN, such that it only creates 1 bean in the Application Context? Remember, these are 3rd party libs that  ***I cannot edit***.

I am using the `@SpringBootApplication` on my Java class containing main method.

Comment: this was an interesting question, it's a pity you never came back to say if my answer did the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having two classes `PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration` in the application is a code smell, and I would first ask myself why there are two classes. The ideal solution is to have one.

As for the Spring exception, it's probably because Spring auto-detects the two classes annotated with `@Configuration`, and generate two beans with the same name (by default the bean name is computed from the class name). You can override the bean name for one of the classes:

```
@Configuration("myPrometheusServletAutoConfig")
public class PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration {
```

Related: [Annotation-specified bean name conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801359/annotation-specified-bean-name-conflicts-with-existing-non-compatible-bean-def)

Comment: @M A this is a legacy application and the 2 classes with conflicting names are dependencies - can I really override it as you stated if its an external JAR being pulled into my project?

Comment: @ennth Do you actually need both? If not, you can exclude one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255224/how-to-exclude-spring-configuration-files-with-configuration-for-dependency-on

Comment: The problem is with external dependencies. You can not override it! And if there is a solution I have not found it :(

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be a comment, but it's far too long for such.

I have not tested this (in case it does not work, I will delete this answer), but can you try? you could do

```
// extend one of the configs
@Configuration(value = "myPrometheusServletAutoConfig")
public class CopyConfig extends com.my.package.path2.PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration {
}
```

Then define a `BeanPostProcessor`:

```
public class MyPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean.getClass().equals(com.my.package.path2.PrometheusServletAutoConfiguration.class)){
            return new CopyConfig();
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

and the register this in your context:

```
@Bean
public MyPostProcessor customBeanFactory() {
    return new MyPostProcessor();
}
```

And then run your application.